# Automatic dimensioning

Tags: cad, autocad

I have set of random points in the workspace as shown in the figure. I want to automatically dimension those points (Linear dimension only) in the best possible way by using any programming language as shown in the right image (for example). Is there any better algorithm for doing it?

[image]

Comment: When it's randomly scattered like that, ordinate dimensions can make it less of a mess... Also would be easier to implement. Also, the "sample figure" on the right hand side would be considered not-great drafting practice from what I was taught, as the dimensions should be drawn outside of the part outline, which here we'll imply as some invisible shape that can go around all the points

Comment: @PeteW thanks. yes at the beginning ordinate dimensions was an option but it has limitations. sometimes we have 100 or more points. that time ordinate would be bit of messy if it fall closer. any solutions to overcome it?

Comment: with 100 points I don't think there is any good option at all. "table dimensionsing" would be the only remotely legible way IMO. Assign each point an identifier (e.g. "A01, A02, etc") and show only that label on the drawing view. Display the dimensions (still ordinate, vs some datum that is also indicated in the view) in a table outside the drawing view.

Comment: @PeteW table dimensionsing is a good idea :). thanks. depends on the number of points we might need to take the decision. but if you could find some pattern in the points (such as rectangular or any other) would your decision change?

Comment: Maybe. I am making lots of guesses and assumptions, I don't know the purpose of the dimension drawing you are generating...

Comment: @PeteW the output dimensions would be used for construction, the points are post locations. Anyway the information you provided very useful

Comment: This seems risky as the way the holes are dimensioned (e g. All off a datum corner Vs from one hole to the next) affects the communication of design intent and also the definition of tolerances on the drawing, so by extension the dimensions of the part that a manufacturer can send you without legal recourse...

Comment: Yep that is vital point @Jonathan R Swift ... Also I should say I am coming from machine-design rather than construction/structural. Was imagining a chassis/baseplate for some complicated device. Don't know if this is ever done in construction, but for something with so much detail, we might make the dimensions "basic" and apply a true-position (geometric tolerancing) callout, possibly grouped into patterns, and design around that...